# How to select distinct values from one column from on table and entire other table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 SELECT  (DISTINCT visits.user_id), purchases FROM visits
```

Trying to do smth like this but it is not working.

Comment: So for a user_id there are 3 purchases, how is the engine supposed to know which of those you want to see?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score -1):

Use aggregation.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT v.user_id, ANY_VALUE(purchases)
FROM visits v
GROUP BY v.user_id;
```

Or, if you want the total number of purchases -- assuming `purchases` is a number:

```
SELECT v.user_id, SUM(purchases)
FROM visits v
GROUP BY v.user_id;
```